# HTTP Authentication in URL with backslash in username

Tags: python, curl, request, urllib2, urllib

I need to HTTP Basic Auth for a REST call. In the username I have to provide a domain (which has a hyphen) and then a backslash to separate it from the username, like this: **DOM-AIN\user_name**. Then the password is pretty benign.

This works fine with curl:

```
curl 'https://DOM-AIN\user_name:password@myurl.com'
```

I need to put this into Python now, but I've tried with requests and urllib/2/3...they don't like the **\**  **:** or the **@**. Even when I URL encode to %40, etc., those get interpreted as an actual **:** and urllib thinks I'm trying to define a port and I get an error: Invalid socket, I think, I forgot.

So I tried passing the username and password in the header using urllib3, but I get an unauthorized access error and I suspect it's because I need to somehow encode the username in the header to account for the backslash (%5C), but that doesn't seem to be working either.

Here is some code that doesn't work:

```
# Attempt 1
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
url1 = https://ws.....
headers = urllib3.util.make_headers(basic_auth='DOM-AIN\user_name:password')
r1 = http.request('GET', url1, headers=headers)
response = r1.data

# Attempt 2
passwordManager = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passwordManager.add_password(None, url, 'DOM-AIN\user_name, password)
authenticationHandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passwordManager)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(authenticationHandler)
data = opener.open(url1)
```

There were some other attempts with request, but I don't have those anymore. I can get the errors of these if it would be useful, but if there is already a known thing I'm doing wrong that would be great...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backslash should be escaped in Python string literals:

```
username = 'DOM-AIN\\user_name' # OR
username = r'DOM-AIN\user_name' # raw-string literal
```

Example:

```
import urllib2, base64

request = urllib2.Request('https://example.com')
credentials = base64.b64encode(username + b':' + password)
request.add_header('Authorization', b'Basic ' + credentials)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Note: unlike `HTTPBasicAuthHandler` code; it always sends the credentials without waiting for `401` response with `WWW-Authenticate` header.

Comment: I tried the double backslash but it didn't work, maybe it's just not being accepted by the server. I will try again, but I also found another method using urllib that most closely replicates how it was done with curl. I provided that below.

Comment: @NikhilHaas: the code above produces `Authorization` header that is identical to the one produced by `curl` command. If it doesn't work then your `curl` command would also fail.

Answer (score 0):

First convert your `DOM-AIN\user_name` into `base64` string. Lets say its `XXXXYYYYYYY`. Now place this `base64` string into the http header like below code with `urllib2`.

```
headers = { 'Authorization:' : 'Basic XXXXYYYYYYY' }
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way using urllib, with [this post's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351272/python-urllib-urlopen-nonnumeric-port) mention of FancyURLopener sending me down the right path. This was the closest I could come to replicating the way it worked in curl, although looking at Sabuj's answer there might be a way to use headers properly, but I haven't tried his method.

```
import urllib
opener = urllib.FancyURLopener()
data = opener.open('https://DOM-AIN**%5C%user_name:password@url.com?whatever_parameters')
response = data.read()
```

It works when I only URL encoded the backslash. Didn't work when I encoded the other characters like **:** and **@**.