# Need to pass a string with single \ character in python

Tags: sql, python-3.x, escaping, pyodbc, credentials

I have looked at various solutions and am familiar with using the \ as an escape character. Im in a situation where I need to pass credentials over pyodbc and in making my connection string I need to pass credentials, unfortunately my username is in the format domain\username . I am continually getting errors because the literal string passed to SQL server is domain\username. I have seen a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22564753/http-authentication-in-url-with-backslash-in-username) on here trying to figure this out for url requests. I tried implementing it and I end up with the same error once the actual credentials are decoded. I've tried all kinds of string and raw string tricks best I can get is either '\ ' (with space behind it) or '\\' being literally passed to SQL Server. Any ideas?

```
#username and password is an argument passed from the console, lets just focus on username issue

username = bytes(sys.argv, 'utf8')
credentials = base64.b64encode(usename, altchars = bytes('\ ', 'utf8') )

cnxnstrng = f'''Driver={SQL Server};
Server=server;
Database=database};
UID={base64.b64decode(credentials)};
PWD=password'''
```

Comment: It looks like you're making things a lot more difficult than they need to be. Backslash is not a "special" character that needs escaping in an ODBC connection string, so `r'domain\username'` should "just work". Please [edit] your question to indicate what specific errors you are getting.

Comment: Yeah I thought that, but I am getting a login error [28000] where it say 'failed to login for user domain\\username' Im thinking that extra \ that's is being passed is causing this, as the actual username is domain/username not domain\\username.

Comment: That's probably just a display artifact similar to what you will see if you do `print(repr(r'hello\world'))`